# How to gracefully undo changes to Ubuntu PATH variable?

Tags: linux, bash, path

Note, I have seen several solutions online for how to change the `PATH` variable, however that is not what I am asking about.

What I would like to do is not hardcode a new `PATH` variable but instead undo changes that installations made to it.

This problem arose because i repeatedly tried to install the same software, hence my `PATH` variable contains repeated and redundant directories.

I am hoping to not hardcode a new `PATH` variable because I'm afraid that in the future if I wanted to install software and have it automatically append to `PATH`, that hardcoding `PATH` would overwrite any such changes.

This is what my current `PATH` looks like when I type `echo $PATH`:

```
/home/douglaswja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/home/douglaswja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/home/douglaswja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/douglaswja/.rvm/bin
```

(Repeats are `ruby-2.6.3`, `ruby-2.6.3@global`, `ruby-2.6.3/bin`)

This is what my `PATH` looks like in `~/etc/environment`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games".
```

Comment: Check all of the bash startup files for the changes. See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PATH` variable can be set in numerous number of files and also custom files created by the user. I'm going to make a list of what I can find or come to mind and describe for you why that particular file is used.

**To investigate your system for places the `PATH` is set these are the places to check.**

```
/etc/bashrc
```

Contains system defaults and aliases used by the bash shell. `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells.

```
/home/user/.bashrc OR ~/.bashrc
```

`.bashrc` is a shell script that Bash runs whenever it is started interactively. It initializes an interactive shell session. You can put any command in that file that you could type at the command prompt.

```
~/.bash_login
```

The shell looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

```
/etc/profile
```

The `/etc/profile` file is not very different however it is used to set system wide environmental variables on users shells.

```
~/.bash_profile
```

is executed for login shells. `bash_profile` is appropriate when you want to set a PATH variable customized for a single user of the system.

```
/etc/environment
```

`/etc/environment` is a system-wide configuration file, which means it is used by all users. It is owned by `root` though, so you need to be an admin user and use `sudo` to modify it.

```
/etc/profile.d
```

Your Linux system will execute all script files ending in .sh in this directory.

```
~/.zprofile
```

and

```
~/.zshrc OR ~/.zshenv
```

`Zsh` is a powerful shell that operates as both an interactive shell and as a scripting language interpreter. While being compatible with the `Bourne shell` (not by default, only if issuing emulate sh), it offers advantages such as improved tab completion and globbing.

```
~/.kshrc OR ~/.kprofile
```

The `Korn shell` uses two startup files, the `.profile` and the `.kshrc`. The `.profile` is read once, by your login `ksh`, while the `.kshrc` is read by each new`ksh`.

THESE ARE WHAT I COULD FIND, CHECK THEM OUT TO SEE IF THE `PATH` VARIABLE IS SET IN THEM, THE ONES YOU HAVE.